# password prompt not visible with python code

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to automate a connection to remote "server2" but I am not getting the password prompt visible to cease that and access the "server2".
Before connecting to server2, and for security reason I need to access first a gateway using username and OPC (one time passcode), for this part the script is working fine, but the second part of the connection to server2 is not working.

My code is:

```py
import socket,time
from ssh2.session import Session

# gateway access
host= '155.90.32.122'
user= 'root'
password=input ('give me the OPC: ')
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,22))

#Access to gateway 
session=Session()
session.handshake(sock)
session.userauth_password(user,password)

channel1= session.open_session()
channel1.shell()

#Access to server2 
channel1.write('ssh server2\n')

#ceasing the password 
channel1.write('rootroot\n')
time.sleep(3)
size,data=channel1.read()
print (data.decode())
channel1.close()
print("exit status : {0}",format(channel1.get_exit_status()))
```

**the output is :**

```
give me the OPC: 0312
Run help to get a list of available commands
egw > ssh server2
Connecting to server2 as user root
exit status : {0} 0
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**while the expected output should be with password prompt :**

```
give me the OPC: 0312
Run help to get a list of available commands
egw > ssh server2
Connecting to server2 as user root
Password :

server2>
```

Comment: note that you have a typo in the last line with the `format`. replace the comma `,` with a dot `.`

Comment: I hope your password isn't really `rootroot`.

Comment: rootroot is just example , it is not the real password :)